# Openlayers 3 dynamic graticule - how to switch it on and off?

Tags: javascript, openlayers-3

I would like to be able to toggle the graticule on and off dynamically, but the graticule documentation doesn't have an unset, just a `setMap()` function.  How do I dynamically add/remove a graticule to the map?

Do I have a secondary empty unused map and `setMap()` to that when I want it to go away, then back to my main map on toggle?

Comment: Did you try `setMap(null)`?

Comment: Contributions to the documentation are always welcome! It's open-source. :)

Comment: I would but I'm still trying to get my head around the whole dev environment - I'm used to a little Grunt, some JS and that's about it - I had to build a custom Ubuntu VM in Virtualbox just to start editing OL (my Windows build attempts were miserable failures)!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to comments, to record:

```
var graticule = new ol.Graticule({
    map: map //Reference to an ol.Map object
});
```

And later, to remove from the map:

```
graticule.setMap(null);
```